# How to convert Vec<u8> into bson::document::Document?

Tags: websocket, rust, binary, bson

I'm gonna receive [`tungstenite::Message`](https://docs.rs/tungstenite/0.11.0/tungstenite/enum.Message.html) which will contain the bson document from the client. I can convert `tungstenite::Message` into `Vec<u8>` but How can I convert it back into [`bson::document::Document`](https://docs.rs/bson/1.0.0/bson/document/struct.Document.html) on the server side?

Something like this:-

```
if msg.is_binary() {
   let bin = msg.into_data();
   let doc = mongodb::bson::Document::from_reader(&mut bin); //getting error
}
```

Error:-

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::vec::Vec<u8>: std::io::Read` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:52:60
    |
52  |             let doc = mongodb::bson::Document::from_reader(&mut bin);
    |                                                            ^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::io::Read` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<u8>`
    | 
   ::: /home/voldimot/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/bson-1.0.0/src/document.rs:530:27
    |
530 |     pub fn from_reader<R: Read + ?Sized>(reader: &mut R) -> crate::de::Result<Document> {
    |                           ---- required by this bound in `bson::document::Document::from_reader`
```

Comment: What error do you get with the code you've posted? Please paste the complete text of the error in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::io::Cursor`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Cursor.html):

```rust
if msg.is_binary() {
   let mut bin = std:::io::Cursor::new(msg.into_data());
   let doc = mongodb::bson::Document::from_reader(&mut bin); 
}
```